# Duplicate block content

Tags: magento2, php

I would like to duplicate the filters block content on layered category pages.
I'm using this code :

```
<referenceContainer name="category.product.list.additional">
    <action method="append">
        <argument name="block" xsi:type="string">catalog.leftnav</argument>
        <argument name="as" xsi:type="string">alias.name</argument>
    </action>
</referenceContainer>
```

but instead of duplicate the block it moves it to the new container and remove it from the left sidebar.

Thanks !

Comment: Has this bounty not been accepted?

Answer (score 2):

Using an additional block (whose class is Mbs\ProductList\Block\LeftNavClone in my example below) that instantiates the block **catalog.leftnav** like below does the effect you seem to aim for:

```xml
<referenceContainer name="category.product.list.additional">
    <block class="Mbs\ProductList\Block\LeftNavClone" name="catalog.leftnav.clone">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="originalBlock" xsi:type="string">catalog.leftnav</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

the code for the block as below:

```php
<?php
    namespace Mbs\ProductList\Block;
        
    class LeftNavClone extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
    {
        protected function _toHtml()
        {
            $clone = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($this->getData('originalBlock'));
            if ($clone) {
               return $clone->toHtml();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This php code was unable to set different phtml file using setTemplateMethod. So i've created my own.


you can use below.

 $clone = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($this->getData('originalBlock'));
            $orgTemplate = $clone->getTemplate();
            if ($clone) {
                $clone->setTemplate('Magento_Theme::html/collapsible-mobile.phtml');
                $html = $clone->toHtml();
                $clone->setTemplate($orgTemplate);
               return $html;
            }
            return '';


It's working fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I added a block to my theme by cloning the block class and adding the before and after tags to make one sit on top of the other. I needed different CCS for mine so I created some new CSS classes. In mine I wanted the new block to sit directly above the old one. See code below.

Note the first block has the before="-" tag and the second block has the after="-" tag.

```xml
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="rd.navbar-wrap" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rd-navbar">
        <container name="rd.navbar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rd-navbar-panel layout_1">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_info_2" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_info_2</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_info" after="-">
                <arguments>
<argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_info</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Once I added these changes to layout.xml in my theme I created a new block in the admin panel with the block identifier "header_info_2" and it showed up correctly. There was quite a few CSS files with the original class header-info so I had to create new custom classes that corresponded to the new blocks design.

The original code block in layout.xml looked like this:

```xml
<referenceContainer name="header.container">
    <container name="rd.navbar-wrap" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rd-navbar">
        <container name="rd.navbar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="rd-navbar-panel layout_1">
            <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_info" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_info</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </container>
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Hope this helps

Below is an image of the 2 blocks on the frontend homepage. The top one is the new one with the new CSS.

[image: New block in Magento 2.3.4 homepage]